# When I parent my head armature to my body armature it moves

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, parent, pose-mode

I want to parent my hat armature to one of the bones in the neck, but when I do it messes up the location. The armature has no previous parent like most articles seem to suggest, and the rotation, location, and scale are all applied.

Comment: is your armature in Rest pose?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found it, you have to select keep transform